# SQL Server user permissions per schema

Tags: sql-server

I would like to get the permissions of every user per schema in SQL Server as the below MySQL query

```
SELECT * FROM mysql.db
```

Comment: USE `select * from information_schema.user_privileges;`

Comment: @majidhajibaba I believe this is a MySQL language. I would like SQL Server query

Comment: I add sql-server tag to find better answer.